# What is the remainder when 50! Divided by 47^2?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I tried to solve it by Wilson theorem and I got 41 but answer is 1927.

Comment: Did you notice that if $50! = q \cdot 47^2 + r$, then $r$ has to be divisible by $47$?

Comment: Didn't get you can you explain in brief....

Comment: Please share your full calculation, so we can see where you might have gone wrong

Comment: Well - ignoring the answer below - you want to calculate my $r$. The LHS is divisible by $47$, as is $q\cdot 47^2$, so $r$ must also be divisible by $47$ . Your answer was not...

Comment: 46!=47k-1      so 50!=(47k-1)*47*48*49*50=>50!/47=(47k-1)*48*49*50=>rem(50!/47^2)=(-1)*1*2*3=-6=41 where I am wrong??? @Peter a g

Comment: @SumitJha the modulus is $47^2$, not $47$.

Comment: @SumitJha On  your previous: your last implication isn't right: $47(47k-1) = 47^2k-47$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 4):

You've probably found $$\frac{50!}{47}\equiv 41\pmod{47}$$ but you were looking for
$$50!\equiv 41\cdot 47\equiv 1927\pmod{47^2}$$